# Question about resolvent set and spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm trying to find the solution of this one:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ a Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Show that

1) $\lambda \in \rho (T) \Longleftrightarrow \bar{\lambda} \in \rho (T^*)$

2) $\sigma (T^*) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : \bar{\lambda} \in \sigma (T)\}$

3) $ \lambda \in \rho (T) \Longrightarrow R_{T^*} (\bar{\lambda}) = R_T(\lambda)^*$.

I tried to write down the definition of resolvent set and spectrum as follows:

\begin{equation}
\rho(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \exists(T-\lambda I)^{-1} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})\}
\end{equation}
 and
\begin{equation}
\sigma(T) = \mathbb{C}-\rho(T)
\end{equation}

But I can't figure out what to do..

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: just dealt with definitions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All what we need is: if $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, then

$A$ is bijective $ \iff A^*$ is bijective

and if $A=T - \lambda I$, then $A^*=T^*- \overline{\lambda} I.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: So if I suppose that there exists $(T-\lambda I)^{-1} = A^{-1}$ then $A$ is bijective and this implies that also $A^*$ as well (and vice-versa). So the result should follows automatically from the definition, right?

Comment: Yes, the results follow easily from the definitions.

Comment: thank you, I really need to grab my old book of linear algebra and check few things again. ^_^"